# Documenting parameters of a function parameter in Kotlin

Tags: documentation, kotlin, higher-order-functions

Let's say I have a higher order function, which registers some sort of a click listener. I can document its purpose and the `listener` parameter that's passed in like so:

```
/**
 * Adds a [listener] that's called when the item is clicked.
 *
 * @param listener The listener to add
 */
fun addClickListener(listener: (count: Int) -> Unit) {
    ...
}
```

My question is, is there a way to document the parameters of the `listener`? This would be `count` in this example. In my actual use case, I have multiple parameters in my listener.

What I've noticed is that the `[listener]` text is clickable in the documentation view where I'm using this function, but it just shows an empty dialog about it. Is there a way to describe the parameters there somehow?

[image]
[image: The listener documentation that comes up]

For now, I've ended up describing the parameters of the listener with `@param` blocks at the `addClickListener` method, but this results in a warning in the IDE, and I'm wondering if there's a more proper way to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of Kotlin 1.1 there is no syntax for documenting the parameters or return value of a function type used as a function parameter. There is an [open YouTrack issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-15529) covering this.